# Illegal Offset error in php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this, that I'm looping through:
Name of Array is $test

```
Array
(
[ven1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => ven1-center1
                [1] => ven1
                [2] => Address
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => ven1-center2
                [1] => ven1
                [2] => Address
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => ven1-center3
                [1] => ven1
                [2] => Address
            )

           .
           .
           .


 [ven2] => Array
    (
        [20] => Array
            (
                [0] => ven2-center1
                [1] => ven2
                [2] => Address
            )

        [21] => Array
            (
                [0] => ven2-center2
                [1] => ven2
                [2] => Address
            )

        [22] => Array
            (
                [0] => ven2-center3
                [1] => ven2
                [2] => Address
            )
```

I have the php code below to loop the whole array, grab all the values of [0] from the innermost dimension, store them into an array with the name of $k.
When I run the code below, I get `Notice: Undefined offset:` for all the values of $c.

```
    for($c = 0; $c < 42; $c++){
        foreach($test as $k =>  $v){
          if($test[$k][$c][1] == $k){
           $k = $test[$k][$c][0];
         }
       }
     }
```

The output am looking for is

```
$ven1 = array("ven1-center1","ven1-center2","ven1-center3","ven1-center4")
$ven2 = array("ven1-center1","ven1-center2","ven1-center3","ven1-center4")
```

Comment: Creating numbered variables like that is almost always wrong. Use an array.

Comment: @Barmar Can you PLEASE explain what you mean?

Comment: Instead of `$ven1` and `$ven2`, you should have an array `$ven`, with `$ven['ven1'] = array("ven1-center1","ven1-center2","ven1-center3","ven1-center4")` and `$ven['ven2'] = array("ven1-center1","ven1-center2","ven1-center3","ven1-center4")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you want... assuming I interpreted your question correctly:

```
foreach($test as $varname => $array){
   foreach($array as $row) {
       if ($row[1] == $varname) ${$varname}[] = $row[0];
   }
}

var_dump($ven1);
var_dump($ven2);
```

Comment: Both $ven1 and $ven2 echoes out exactly. When I `print_r( ${$varname})` I do not get an array of $ven1 and $ven2. Is this normal? Also can what notation is ` ${$varname}` ?
Thanks

Comment: It's called a _variable variable_. http://us3.php.net//manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: `${$varname}[]` means take the variable with name `$varname` - so in this case, `$varname` contains `"ven1"`, so we are taking the variable `$ven1`. Normally you can do `$$varname`, but since it's an array, we have to use `{}` because it's ambiguous if the `[]` refers to `$varname` or `$$varname`.